# How to Synchronise calendar with Textbox in asp.net.

Tags: asp.net

I am new in .net developement please suggest me,

How to Synchronise calendar with Textbox in asp.net.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should elaborate your question more since it's not clear what's being asked. You should also show what you've tried so far and what doesn't work. Please read the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [especially this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) to learn how to write good questions on SO :)

Comment: What calendar ? What Textbox ? please to get help you need to place a real question with some details code etc....

Comment: i mean to ask,when i select date from calender it will be displayed in textbox in asp.net calender control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you will use Ajax toolkit calender control.
Its working as per our requirement as per my carrier experiance..

for more information 
[AJAX TOOLKIT CALENDER](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)

Comment: but I dont have ajax toolkit ,is there any other way to do this?

Comment: U can download it from the following link : http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/76976

according to your framework `3.5` or `4`installing it is so easy.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that:

- [Calendar](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) , [AjaxToolKit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_Calendar_Simple.ashx)
- [RadDatePicker](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datepicker/custompopup/defaultcs.aspx)
- [JQuery DatePicker](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/07/15/integration-of-jquery-datetimepicker-in-asp-net-website-part-1.aspx)
- [JQuery DatePicker.](http://elegantcode.com/2008/05/06/using-jquery-datepicker-in-aspnet/), and [this one](http://www.misfitgeek.com/using-jquery-ui-datepicker-in-an-asp-net-application/)